# Calculating Population-Weighted Exposure level using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, weighted-overlay

I am trying to calculate population-weighted exposure level (PWEL) of particulate matter. I have raster layer of both particulate matter and population. The equation to calculate PWEL is:

[image: equation to calculate PWEL]

Pi is population in grid i and Ci is average particulate matter concentration. I have tried raster calculator but it is giving me PWEL = Ci.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What formula are you using in raster calculator?

Comment: I cannot do the summation, so I use (Pi x Ci)/Pi. Mathematically Pi is canceling with the denominator.

Comment: Cell-wise it has to drop out.  The formula makes sense only if it aggregates over a number of cells.  Sum up \Sigma{Pi} separately over each aggregation into a population for that aggregation, and divide the \sigma{Ci*Pi} for each aggregation by the aggregation's total population.  Maybe think of it as PWEL_j = \Sigma{Ci*Pi}/Pj

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dave X. Could you please elaborate the answer, I couldn't get it?

Comment: If you have 30 cells 'i' in county 'k' then you add up the 30 Ci*Pi and divide by the population in county 'k' = sum(Pi) to get a PWEL for county 'k'.

Comment: I have one raster layer for population data, one raster layer for particulate matter concentration, and one raster layer for district boundary. I have tried your suggestion using raster calculator, but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: Thanks @Yacob Tesfamariam, the solution you posted above is sound. I noticed that you have to have an independent Pi and it's associated Ci value when calculating the PWEL. If you use a uniform Ci value across all Pi's, the PWEL value will always be equal to Ci.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Dave X for the suggestions. I haven't slept over this problem and based on your suggestion I found the solution. What I did is I convert the PM10 and Population data into vector (point). Then I match PM10 value closer to the population count. Finally, I perform the calculation over the district shapefile.